# Reg Expression in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, connection-string

I gave the above string,I want to get the serveripaddress,DB1,uid and **** these values from that string.

Comment: At least show us what you already got. This question otherwise looks like "Hey, SO, solve my task for me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to parse a connection string when the BCL can do it for you:

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var provider = builder.Provider;
var dataSource = builder.DataSource;
var initialCatalog = builder["Initial Catalog"];
var userID = builder["User ID"];
var password = builder["Password"];
```

Note that for an OLE DB connection string, only the standard cross-provider properties have strongly-typed property names, all the rest are accessed via the indexer.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a regex.

Parse the connection string using [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) and then access the keys from that.

```
var b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myConnectionString);
var dataSource = b["Data Source"]; 
// etc.
```

Much easier, more maintainable and more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

```
data source=([^;]*);Initial Catalog=([^;]*);user id=([^;]*);Password=([^;"]*)
```

You then have the matches in groups 1 to 4. If you get bored you can name the groups; helps readability of the code, though rarely helps readability of the regex itself.

Comment: +1 since subramani  only says thank you, and never heard of accepting or voting up apparently

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier to split value using ';' char and then split every item by '=' char?

This way your connection string could be edited by users and even item order could be changed.